# Are we free to choose what happened, if we don't know what did?

Tags: existentialism

Do any existentialists talk about freedom to choose facts, not values, given that we don't know either way? I don't mean anything as lofty as the existence of god, but what memories are confabulated, what explains someone's diappearance, stuff like that.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "to choose facts"? - Could you please clarify your point.

Comment: i have given examples @JoWehler

Comment: I cannot see the example.

Comment: "what memories are confabulated, what explains someone's diappearance, stuff like that." @JoWehler ???

Comment: I know I can't forget or remember things at will. But I do wonder how do you feel about it. Do you feel like you are free to choose what you remember?

Answer (score 1):

I think the notion of underdetermination of facts about the past, or even the present, by empirical evidence is quite uncontroversial even outside of existentialist circles. We do it all the time and infer to (what we consider) the best explanation - in history, cosmology, paleontology. Has anyone seen the Big Bang? (of course that's a ridiculous question, given what the Big Bang was, but nevertheless illustrates my point)

From a strictly existentialist standpoint, however, I would say that the past of a human being is never strictly determined by "the facts" but by their present self-identification. That's why death is significant for existentialists - it brings this process of constant re-identification to an abrupt end and gives a determinate answer to the question of "Who was X?". Perhaps that addresses the question.

Comment: what sort of things do you mean by "self identification"?

Comment: @user66697 The standard existentialist idea of 'inventing one's meaning of life'. But of course there's also a socio-political dimension to it, related to the fact that we're influenced by the society's stereotypes which supposedly prevent us from living truly authentic lives, as "The Second Sex" and similar works show.

Answer (score 1):

You are always free to speculate about alternative possibilities where there is no evidence to rule them out. What you cannot do is to insist upon the correctness of one possibility in the absence of supporting evidence; or, rather, if you do insist you are being unreasonable.

Comment: what about beliefs rather than discussion?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.txst.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/ought-is.html

In inference to the best explanation. We may be forgiven for it, but it is not valid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community i'm the only one who cited anything! jfc, say whatever you like i guess